# Can I merge two arrays and still know the origin of each element?

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have two integer arrays x and y. And I have to merge into another array for sorting (or any other data structure). But when I choose an element from the merged array, I might also need the info of the element as to which array it originally belonged to? Is there a way to arrange the elements for that?

Comment: No, not directly with `int` type. You would need another data structure, that would also store the information about the array.

Comment: Not good in some cases but: if you know `array x` have 10 ints and `array y` have 15 ints and you merge it in a sequential order you could suppose in the `array z` you have from 0 - 10 `array x`, 11 - 24 `array y` Then check the index and you could say if it's from array X or Y.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno sorting will not make the sequential order

Comment: @NiksTyagi oh sorry, i didn't read "sorting". My error.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno its ok mistake are done by human being :) :)

Comment: If you can also keep the original arrays, you could check if some value is in either (or both, if there can be duplicates) of them to see where it came from. Perhaps convert original arrays to sets for faster lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use maps to keep track of original and final indices of each integer, but if there are multiple `int`s of the same value, that could get tricky. I am in agreement with Tim's approach: create a new class.

```
class IntWithLocations {
    int value;
    int original_array;
    int original_index;
    int final_index;
}
```

Thus, from the final sorted array or list (which will be of the type `IntWithLocations`, not `int`), you can retrieve the original array (`x` or `y`) as well as the index of this element in that original array.

Comment: If keeping track of indexes, then it should not matter if there are identical values. Indexes are never identical anyway.

Comment: What if the sorting algorithm is not safe? Keeping track of indices will not be trivial then.

Comment: I assume you mean "stable". Well, if values are identical, and there can be duplicates, it might be best to just have that, "value was in both original arrays".

Answer (score 3):

Create a class to store the integers and also have information of where that value came from.

Fill the arrays with instances of that class and then merge and sort them as you like. You always know where an element came from.